# PackageNotFoundError when creating new Conda environment

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, deep-learning, conda

After installing Anaconda or Miniconda and trying to create first environment, I'm getting the following error:

**PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
  - package_name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when you first run `conda config` (**.condarc** is created) by default it contains

```
create_default_packages:
  - tensorflow
  - PACKAGE_NAME
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

So it tries to fetch a package called **PACKAGE_NAME** which surprisingly does not exist.

Simply removing `- PACKAGE_NAME` line from **.condarc** fixes the issue.